# Have an error with Realtime Database from Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

```
    // db.js file

    import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
    import "firebase/database"
    
    const config = {
        apiKey: "" ...
    }
    
    const db = firebase.initializeApp(config)
    export default db

    // App.vue file


    import { reactive, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
    import db from "./db.js";
    
    const SendMessage = () => {
          const messagesRef = db.database().ref("messages")
    
          if(inputMessage.value === "" || inputMessage.value === null) {
            return
          }
    
          const message = {
            username: state.username,
            content: inputMessage.value
          }
    
          messagesRef.push(message)
          inputMessage.value = ""
        }
```

I try to make a little chat app with Vue.js and Firebase.
So i don't understand because i receive this when i try to send a message :
*db_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_.default.database is not a function
at Proxy.SendMessage (App.vue?3dfd:63:1)

I think it's about the import but i try to change for the V9 of firebase but that's didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase V9 is build in functional aproach. Im working with firestore usually give me a sign if some thing not working.

db.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getDatabase, ref, push, child, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/database'

const config = {
  apiKey: "" ...
}

const firebase = initializeApp(config)
const db = getDatabase()

function addMessage(path, message) {
  message.createAt = serverTimestamp() // On database side database will assign current
  // timestamp to this field so you will be able to order data
  // from newest to oldest for example.
  return push(child(ref(db, path)), message)
}
export { addMessage }
```

App.vue file

```js
import { reactive, onMounted, ref } from 'vue'
import { addMessage } from "./db.js";

const SendMessage = async () => {
  if (!inputMessage.value) return 
  // line above will check are value is "" or null by throwing
  // false and using ! in front you changing it to true.

  const message = {
    username: state.username,
    content: inputMessage.value
  }

  const result = await addMessage('path to data in tree', message)
  // async/await will await until data is saved in database and then will do code bellow.
  console.log(result.key) // If you await you can read result if result is not void.
  inputMessage.value = ""
}
```

If you use `ref()` in .vue files make database operations outside of vue files database have same `ref()` function but they work different. You can allso change name of one function in import line `import { ref as dbRef } from 'firebase/database'`

Comment: Yes i see, but child is from what ? Firebase ?

Comment: @JennaDiop Yes sorry i forgot to put in imports. Please vote up and mark bird under votes if my answer is correct and helped you.